# Cannot hide toolbar when scrolling recyclerview doing all things posted in this forum

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, toolbar

As the tittle shows, I cannot hide the toolbar when I scroll a recyclerview.
I have two tabs filled with a fragmet with a recyclerview inside both

Here my XML code. Each recyclerview have the line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and the tollbar have the flag `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"`

Fragment 1

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="4dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ftvl_RecyclerView"
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Fragment 2

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="4dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ftasl_RecyclerView"
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_fall_down"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

AppBar_MainScreen

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Screens.MainScreen.MainScreen.MainScreen">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/cms_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:title="Disco App">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/cms_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="30dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabMode="fixed">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_screen" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/cms_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Can anyone help me? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh! If you look at your `AppBarLayout` it is wrapped inside `LinearLayout`. But `AppBarLayout` should ALWAYS be direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. If still doesn't work then try to wrap your `RecyclerView` inside of `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: thx you, but now I have two new problems, first one: the toolbar scroll and the recyclerview scroll isn't synchronized. Second one: the firts item of the recyclerview is behind the toolbar and the tabs. Could you help?

Comment: @ArAadityaBrahmbhatt I only needed to add the line "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" " inside the viewpager and magically, all bugs were fixed, haha